# Android Studio 2.2 Preview all screen sizes missing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, layout-editor

Android studio before 2.2 version at the xml design screen there was a view like  "Preview all screen sizes" (check the image) but I cannot find that in Android Studio 2.2 Beta 2.
[image: "Preview all screen sizes"]

My Android Studio version is:

> Android Studio 2.2 Beta 2 
>   Build #AI-145.3200535, built on August 18, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Could you help me where is it, how can I open it?

Comment: i think in 2.2 this option is removed..i don't know if they will implement this again though..

Comment: Which preview version of 2.2 are you using??

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The option to preview all screen sizes is not available in Android Studio 2.2 Beta 2. However, you can resize the preview screen to see how your layout would look on different screen sizes, as shown in the attached gif.

[image: Android Studio 2.2 Beta 3 Preview Screen resize example]

Comment: **preview all screen** option was gr8 & handy. We really miss that and hope google will come back with it soon.

Comment: @ManishJain correct. Although this one is a bit dynamic than the previous feature. Still, wish they just add this and not remove the all prev feat.

Comment: the year 2019, Android Studio 3.4.1 does not support it... meanwhile, there are more and more different screen sizes out there. They need to do smth. about it

Answer (score 4):

While preview all screen sizes seems to be gone, it is possible in 2.3 to view more than one screen size at the same time.

Right-click on the activity_main.xml (or whichever xml file) tab, and from the pop-up menu select split-vertically or split-horizontally.

This will create a second xml tab that can use a different screen for design/text. This can be repeated for more tabs, and the tabs can be "torn off" to float separately.

Comment: the split windows will sync up every time you change the device :(

Answer (score 1):

The Previews are back!

Try this:

1. open your layout xml
2. open the new tab **Layout Validation**

If you can't find the tab, try double-shift and search for "Layout Validation".

[image]

([source](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#layout-validation))