# Android: two previews of the layout for different devices

Tags: android, layout

Hy,

I know I can launch my app on multiple devices at the same time but is there a way to view two previews of the layout for different devices at the same time without having to launch the avds?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165166/android-studio-2-2-preview-all-screen-sizes-missing

Comment: Layout Previews had been removed from Android Studio, but are now back under a different tab https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333246/1208581

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio 2.2 once you have opened your layout file, you can preview the layout for different devices like that :

[image]

Comment: Hy, but at the same time?

Comment: Hi, Looks like they removed this feature in Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Right-click on the activity_main.xml tab, and from the pop-up menu select split-vertically or split-horizontally.

This will create a second xml tab that can use a different screen for design/text. This can be repeated for more tabs, and the tabs can be "torn off" to float separately.

Comment: that does not work. There is still only one preview window.